# If $u$ satisfies the Laplace equation, show that both $xu$ and $yu$ satisfy the biharmonic equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> If $u$ satisfies the Laplace equation $\nabla^2u\equiv u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$, show that both $xu$ and $yu$ satisfy the biharmonic equation$$\nabla^4\begin{pmatrix}xu\\\\yu\end{pmatrix}=0$$but $xu$ and $yu$ will not satisfy the Laplace equation.

So, I don't really understand what that parenthesis next to the biharmonic equation is. Is it a combination of some sorts? or a vector? Either way, how do I go about operating it in the biharmonic equation? Any help/idea to get started with this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: The parentheses mean that both $\nabla^4(xu)=0$ and $\nabla^4(yu)=0$. Just differentiate. For instance, you can prove that the laplacian of $xu$ is $2u_x$. Then check that the laplacian of $u_x$ must be zero. Likewise for $yu$.

Comment: Thanks so much to both of you guys! I'll get working now. And I'll follow José Santo's advice in the future

Comment: It's element wise since the biharmonic operator is scalar.

Answer (score 0):

For the first equation, by direct computations we obtain:
$$
\nabla^4(xu)=\partial_x^4(xu)+2\partial_x^2\partial_y^2(xu)+\partial_y^4(xu)=x\partial_x^2\big(\partial_x^2u+\partial_y^2u\big)+x\partial_y^2\big(\partial_x^2u+\partial_y^2u\big)+4\partial_x\big(\partial_x^2u+\partial_y^2u\big)=0,
$$
where in the last equality we have used the fact that $\partial_x^2u+\partial_y^2u=0$. The second equations follows exactly the same computations.